# List the five upper Jordan canonical forms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

List the five upper Jordan canonical forms for a $4\times 4$ matrix $A$ with a real eigenvalue $\lambda$ of multiplicity $4$ and give the corresponding geometric multiplicities  in each case. What is the form of the solution of the intial value problem $\bf{\dot{x}}=Ax$

## Solution so far

The five upper Jordan canonical forms are
$$ 
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   \lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & \lambda & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 &\lambda & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda
  \end{array} } \right]
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda   & 0  & 0  & 0 \\
0         & \lambda & 0  & 0 \\
0         & 0  & \lambda & 0 \\
0    & 0  & 0  & \lambda 
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda   & 1  & 0  & 0 \\
0         & \lambda & 0  & 0 \\
0         & 0  & \lambda & 0 \\
0    & 0  & 0  & \lambda 
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda   & 1  & 0  & 0 \\
0         & \lambda & 1  & 0 \\
0         & 0  & \lambda & 0 \\
0    & 0  & 0  & \lambda 
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda   & 1  & 0  & 0 \\
0         & \lambda & 0  & 0 \\
0         & 0  & \lambda & 1 \\
0    & 0  & 0  & \lambda 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
But I am having issue finding the solution of the ivp in each case. I am not sure what the matrix A is in each case.

Comment: If you haven't gotten the geometric multiplicity part yet, the number of Jordan blocks for a given eigenvalue is its geometric multiplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is $x(t)=e^{tA}x_0$. For a Jordan block such as
$$
         J=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda\end{array} \right]
         = \lambda I+\left[\begin{array}{cccc}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right] = \lambda I + N,
$$
the matrices $I$ and $N$ commute, which allows you to distribute the sum over the exponential:
\begin{align}
       e^{tJ} & = e^{t\lambda I}e^{tN} \\
       & = e^{\lambda t}e^{tN} \\
       & = e^{\lambda t}\left[I+tN+\frac{1}{2!}t^2N^2+\frac{1}{3!}t^3N^3\right].
\end{align}
The series terminates at $N^3$ because $N^4=0$. You get
$$
   e^{tA} = e^{\lambda t}\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
                                1 & t & \frac{t^2}{2!} & \frac{t^3}{3!} \\
                                0 & 1 & t & \frac{t^2}{2!} \\
                                0 & 0 & 1 & t \\
                                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
                               \end{array}\right]
$$
The only part missing is the transition matrix $A = V^{-1}JV$ where $J$ is in Jordan canonical form. $e^{tA} = V^{-1}e^{tJ}V$, and $e^{tJ}$ consists of blocks of the form shown above.